# How to save the xml file in the directory I want (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, save

There is some filled document `xml Document doc = builder.newDocument ();` which I want to save to the `assets` folder of my application, how can I do this?  I climbed to the Internet, but I could not find information, I was probably looking bad (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assets/` directory is a directory on your development machine. It is not a directory on the device, and assets are read-only in your application.

Please save your XML to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).